# Unique values only when data in another column matches

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

SQL-Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d142/1

```
CREATE TABLE steps 
    (
        id int auto_increment primary key, 
        step_day varchar(10),
        title varchar(32), 
        description varchar(500),
        step_order tinyint unsigned not null
    );


-- Test insert
INSERT INTO steps
(step_day, title, description, step_order)
VALUES
('monday',   'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('saturday', 'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('monday',   'Step 2', 'Do some stuff.', '2'),
('saturday', 'Step 2', 'Do more stuff.', '2');
```

The data in the Test insert is currently ok, but I would like to protect the columns 'title' and 'step_order' from duplicate entries only when data in the 'step_day' column is the same.

So...

```
('monday',   'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('monday',   'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1')
```

...is bad, but...

```
('monday',   'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('saturday', 'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1')
```

...is ok.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE steps 
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    step_day varchar(10),
    title varchar(32)not null, 
    description varchar(500),
    step_order tinyint unsigned not null,
    CONSTRAINT uc_steps UNIQUE (step_day,title,step_order)
);
```

this will allow you to have unique data in step_day,title,step_order.

this will allow you to add

```
INSERT INTO steps
(step_day, title, description, step_order)
VALUES
('monday',   'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('saturday', 'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1');
```

but not

```
INSERT INTO steps
(step_day, title, description, step_order)
VALUES
('monday', 'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1'),
('monday', 'Step 1', 'Do some stuff.', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT id,
       step_day,
       title,
       description,
       step_order
FROM steps
GROUP BY step_day,title;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d142/5)